# Adapting styles to Ionic of existing web page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working on a project with an implemented website and they asked me to place Capacitator with Ionic, the styles are already created. I wanted to know how to replicate the web styles for the web page.

I'm going to leave an image below as seen on the website with Pixel 2 and as seen in the Pixel 2 emulator. Would I have to do all the styles again? or how would I implement it.

[image]

My configuration for ionic.config.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "react"
}
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap on the page

Comment: Is your project, already a web app with ionic ? Because you can add Capacitor without Ionic. Check : https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started